# Not able to load SVG with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

when trying to import the following in a React component:

`import "bpmn-font/dist/css/bpmn-embedded.css";`

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bpmn-font/dist/font/bpmn.svg?61125153 10:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-svg-loader/lib/loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       props = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["styles"]);
|
>   return <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {...props} />;
| });
```

with the following webpack config:

```
{
 test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
   {
     loader: "babel-loader"
   },
   {
     loader: "react-svg-loader",
     options: {
      jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
     }
   }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by using:

```
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          exclude: excludeArray,
          loader: "svg-inline-loader"
        },
```